# backpressure is not properly handled in akka-streams

Tags: akka-stream

I wrote a simple stream using akka-streams api assuming it will handle my source but unfortunately it doesn't. I am sure I am doing something wrong in my source. I simply created an iterator which generate very large number of elements assuming it won't matter because akka-streams api will take care of backpressure. What am I doing wrong, this is my iterator.

```
def createData(args: Array[String]): Iterator[TimeSeriesValue] = {
var data = new ListBuffer[TimeSeriesValue]()
for (i <- 1 to range) {
  sessionId = UUID.randomUUID()
  for (j <- 1 to countersPerSession) {
    time = DateTime.now()
    keyName = s"Encoder-${sessionId.toString}-Controller.CaptureFrameCount.$j"
    for (k <- 1 to snapShotCount) {
      time = time.plusSeconds(2)
      fValue = new Random().nextLong()
      data += TimeSeriesValue(sessionId, keyName, time, fValue)
      totalRows += 1
    }
  }
}
data.iterator
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is primarily in the line

```
data += TimeSeriesValue(sessionId, keyName, time, fValue)
```

You are continuously adding to the `ListBuffer` with a "very large number of elements".  This is chewing up all of your RAM.  The `data.iterator` line is simply wrapping the massive ListBuffer blob inside of an iterator to provide each element one at a time, it's basically just a cast.

Your assumption that "it won't matter because ... of backpressure" is partially true that the akka Stream will process the `TimeSeriesValue` values reactively, but you are creating a large number of them even before you get to the Source constructor.

If you want this iterator to be "lazy", i.e. only produce values when needed and not consume memory, then make the following modifications (note: I broke apart the code to make it more readable):

```
def createTimeSeries(startTime: Time, snapShotCount : Int, sessionId : UUID, keyName : String) = 
  Iterator.range(1, snapShotCount)
          .map(_ * 2)
          .map(startTime plusSeconds _)
          .map(t => TimeSeriesValue(sessionId, keyName, t, ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong()))

def sessionGenerator(countersPerSession : Int, sessionID : UUID) = 
  Iterator.range(1, countersPerSession)
          .map(j => s"Encoder-${sessionId.toString}-Controller.CaptureFrameCount.$j")
          .flatMap { keyName => 
    createTimeSeries(DateTime.now(), snapShotCount, sessionID, keyName)
  }

object UUIDIterator extends Iterator[UUID] {
  def hasNext : Boolean = true
  def next() : UUID = UUID.randomUUID()
}

def iterateOverIDs(range : Int) = 
  UUIDIterator.take(range)              
              .flatMap(sessionID => sessionGenerator(countersPerSession, sessionID))
```

Each one of the above functions returns an Iterator.  Therefore, calling `iterateOverIDs` should be instantaneous because no work is immediately being done and de mimimis memory is being consumed.  This iterator can then be passed into your Stream...

Comment: Hi Ramon, Thanks a lot for the response. Extremely helpful.I don't understand your code fully yet but very elegant stuff and worked for me.  how do I become expert in Scala style thinking, I am having hard time thinking in immutable asynchronous and functional. Any preferred readings or exercises ?

Comment: @Lahiru You are welcome.  For an intro to scala/fp I definitely recommend the coursera course: https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun .  The session is not active right now but I believe you can still watch the videos.  Happy Hacking!

Comment: @Lahiru The "functional programming in scala" book is very good to make you think in FP style and has a good learning curve.